# Javascript: Call function on change of textbox value

Tags: javascript

I want to fire a function when some textbox value changes. I tried using $j('#textbox').on(inout propertychange change - but that is not getting fired for some reason.

Can someone please suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: Post some more code so we can see what/why may be broken.

Comment: It's `"input"` not `inout`. (Voting to close for a simple typographical error).

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake while typing here, and not in the code.
$j('#textboxName').on('input propertychange change',function() {
 alert("saving");
});

Answer (score -1):

Try `$('#textbox').on('keyup', callback);`